# How can Google Analytics track visits to non-html pages?

Tags: google-analytics

For example, in Google Analytics I see it tracking visits to .swf and .jpg files on my website. But I thought GA only works on pages that have the javascript embed code in them - something that's impossible with a flash or image file. Any thoughts? Genuinely curious.

Comment: Maybe you have a customization that does that. You should provide an example maybe. It's not default or normal.

Answer (score 0):

Someone just pointed out to me that the image and swf files that were showing up on GA are linked to from html pages on my site. So it seems that GA is smart enough to use the GA code from a linked file's html page to initialize the tracking.

Answer (score 0):

GA cannot track files without tracking code (and it wouldn't be "smart" if it did, either, since this would make metrics like page impressions useless - after all a single page comprises lots of files likes images, swfs, css etc).

When you find jpg-extensions etc. in you reports it's usually a 404 error page that is served with the extension of the requested (but missing) file.